# Differential op-amp vs non-inverting op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Suppose you have to amplify a signal with a gain of 2 .
The signal is referenced to ground, which means V1 is zero.
Is there any reason why one would use this circuit below instead of a normal non-inverting amplifier. 
[image: https://www.electronicshub.org/differential-amplifier/]
Picture obtained from https://www.electronicshub.org/differential-amplifier/

So in that case what is the difference between this circuit and the "normal" non-inverting amplifier were R2=zero and R4= removed.
The only difference I see, is that with the differential amplifier you are able to achieve a gain less than 1.
Are there any more reasons?accuracy?etc

Comment: No - I don`t think that there are any other reasons for using such a voltage divider...

Comment: The differential input is useful if the ground of the source and the amplifier are not identical - it can reject ground noise and avoid causing a ground loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of that 4-resistor circuit is the flexibility of centering Vout to whatever you wish, done by unGrounding that R4 and biasing to your desired Vout_center.

Comment: Ohh yes...this may make sense for single supply systems.